# encode video through windows command line

Tags: video, command-line, windows

I am trying to integrate the Windows command line functionality of Blender into a program I am writing to perform some ProRes/XDCam to DnxHD video encodes. I am currently using FFMPEG to perform DnxHD encodes but would like to test out Blender to see if there are any quality differences. Only problem is I am really confused on how to do this through the command line with Blender. My current FFMPEG command looks something like this:

```
E:\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg -y -i "C:\testing\somefile.mov" -c:v dnxhd -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv422p -r 29.97 -b:v 145M -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ab 1500k -ar 48000 -threads 1 "DnxHDOutput.mov"
```

Could any of you provide some sample command line arguments to get this working or provide me with a guide/link on how to do this?

Comment: AFAIK Blender uses ffmpeg, so I don't know if the result would be any different..

Comment: I was under the same understanding however; I was reading a post in which it appears blender is able to better handle the input color spacing of videos much better than FFMPEG which is why I wanted to perform some tests..

Comment: Here is the forum post which outlines a comparison of FFMPEG and Blender for DnxHD ..http://community.avid.com/forums/t/60895.aspx